# div element not filling to the height of its container div

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETYzR/))

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<div class="main_container">

    <div class="left_container">
    </div>

    <div class="right_container">
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
div.main_container {
    background: #000; 
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

div.left_container {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 220px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

div.right_container {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: 715px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I can't seem to get the left (red) container to fill the height of the main container, where the content of the right container has the possibility to increase the height of the main container (a non-jQuery solution).

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `position:relative` on the main_container.

Since the left column has `height:100%` it will be the same height as its parent.  Under the former code, this element's parent was the document since it had `position:absolute`.  Adding `position:relative` to the container causes it to become the parent of the left column, causing the height of the column to adjust to its parents height.

```
   div.main_container {
        background: #000;
        border: none;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 400px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETYzR/3/

Comment: and thank you for the explanation too, sometimes more important than just getting a solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

not `none`, use `0px`

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Also - `none` is perfectly valid in CSS